# Imprimir variable dentro de mensaje flash Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy tratando de imprimir una variable '@feriados' que la obtengo de una query y que contiene una palabra, junto con un mensaje flash de la siguiente manera. Es posible hacer esto?

> flash[:error] = 'Dia no disponible por feriado: "#{@feriados}" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franco, para tomar el valor de una variable se usan comillas dobles, asi debe quedar el codigo:

```
flash[:error] = "Dia no disponible por feriado: #{@feriados}"
```

La principal diferencia es que las comillas simples se toman como literales, mientras que las comillas dobles admiten interpolaciones de cadenas y el conjunto completo de secuencias de escape.

Comment: Tienes razón, la verdad se me re paso. Muchas gracias, ahora si me funciona..